# Memoization of redundant paths

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, memoization

I am solving a question where there is a grid with r rows and c columns. We start at the top left corner cell, and end at the bottom right corner cell. The constraint is we can move only once cell at a time, either downward or right. Also some of the cells may be black listed. The question is to find the total no. of ways we can go from source to the target.

This is my solution which is straightforward but runs in exponential time:

```
int count(boolean[][] array, int r, int c)
{
    if ((r < 0 || c < 0) || !array[r][c]) return 0;
    if (r == 0 && c == 0) return 1;
    return count(array, r - 1, c) + count(array, r, c - 1);
}
```

The problem I am having is while memoizing this.

1. Can memoization make this solution be made more efficient?
2. If so, then I cannot blacklist all the cells that are in a path that fails because there might be other paths through those cells which may lead to target. So I'm confused so as to what I should cache here and where do I add the additional check to avoid checking on paths I have already gone through.
3. If (1) was yes, then if there were no cells blacklisted, then I was wondering if the memoization would have served any purpose at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can memoization make this solution be made more efficient?

Yes!

> If so, then I cannot blacklist all the cells that are in a path that fails because there might be other paths through those cells which may lead to target.

Correct.

> So I'm confused so as to what I should cache here and where do I add the additional check to avoid checking on paths I have already gone through.

Here's what you do.

Make an r x c 2-d array of nullable integers, let's call it `a`.  The meaning of the array is "`a[x][y]` gives the number of paths from (x, y) to (r-1, c-1)" -- this is supposing that (r-1, c-1) is the "exit" cell that we're trying to get to.

The array will start with every element null. That's great. Null means "I don't know".

Fill in every "blocked" cell in the array with zero.  That means "there is no way to get from this cell to the exit".

If `a[r-1][c-1]` is zero, then the exit is blocked, and we're done. The answer to every query is zero because there is no way to get to the exit.  Let's assume the exit cell is not blocked.

There is one way to get from the exit cell to itself, so fill in `a[r-1][ c-1]` with 1.

Now the algorithm proceeds like this:

- We are asked for a solution starting from cell `(x, y)`.
- Consult the array. If it is null then recurse on the right and down neighbours, and fill in the array at `[x][y]` with the *sum* of those answers
- Now the array is definitely filled in, so return `a[x][y]`.

Let's work an example. Suppose we have

```
n  n  n
n  n  0
n  n  1
```

And we are asked for the solution for (0, 1).  We don't have a solution.  So we try to find the solutions for (1, 1) and (0, 2).

We don't have a solution for (1, 1).  So we have to get solutions for (1, 2) and (2, 1).

(1, 2) we've got. It's 0.

(2, 1) we don't have but (2, 2) we do, and that's the only neighbour.  (2, 2) is 1, so we fill in (2, 1):

```
n  n  n
n  n  0
n  1  1
```

Now we have enough information to fill in (1, 1):

```
n  n  n
n  1  0
n  1  1
```

We still haven't done (0, 2). It has one neighbour which is zero, so that's:

```
n  n  0
n  1  0
n  1  1
```

And now we can fill in (0, 1)

```
n  1  0
n  1  0
n  1  1
```

Which is what we were looking for, so we're done.

Alternative solution: Pre-compute the array.

- We start by filling in all the zeros and the one at the exit as before.
- Now fill in the rightmost column going from the bottom up: it is all ones, until you get to the first zero, at which point it becomes all zeros.
- Now fill in the bottommost row going right to left. Again, it is all ones, until you get to the first zero, at which point it becomes all zeros.
- Now we have enough information to fill in the second-from-the-right column and the second-from-the-bottom row; do you see how?
- Proceed like that until the entire array is filled in.
- And now all the answers are in the array.

Example:

first step:

```
n  n  n
n  n  0
n  n  1
```

Fill in the outer row and column:

```
n  n  0
n  n  0
1  1  1
```

Fill in the next row and column:

```
n  1  0
2  1  0
1  1  1
```

And the last:

```
3  1  0
2  1  0
1  1  1
```

And we're done; the whole problem is solved.

> if there were no cells blacklisted, then I was wondering if the memoization would have served any purpose at all.

If there are no cells blacklisted then the array looks like this:

```
20 10  4  1
10  6  3  1
 4  3  2  1
 1  1  1  1
```

which is a shape you should have seen before and know how to compute each element directly.  Hint: you've usually seen it as a triangle, not a square.

Comment: Before even reading the answer, thanks a lot for taking the time to write, I really appreciate it! It will take me some time as I go through it and try to understand. Please don't mind if I get back to you with any questions I have on it!

Comment: @rgamber: You're welcome; I note that I am accidentally and not on purpose using a different convention for direction than you are; you are characterizing the exit square as (0, 0) and I'm characterizing it at (r-1, c-1).  Either is fine, just pick a convention and stick to it.

Comment: Actually in my code I was printing out the paths when I reach the source cell (0, 0) successfully. So as the recursion unfolds, the path that is printed starts at (0,0) and ends at (r-1,c-1). But I see what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, it works and is exactly what I was looking for! In retrospect I see that its just like the simple memoization we do for a fibonacci recursion but in 2 dimensions. And I feel pretty stupid for not thinking of it right away.

Comment: Any pointers or tips on how I can improve on these kind of problems would be appreciated as well!

Comment: @rgamber: It just takes practice. Exercise: a "bt string" is either `x` or `(` followed by two bt strings, followed by `)`. Suppose we count `x`'s in bt strings. There is one bt string with one: `x`.  There is one with two: `(xx)`.  There are two with three `(x(xx))` and `((xx)x)`. Problem 1: Given an integer n, how many bt strings are there with that many `x`s?  Problem 2: Make a list of them. (Only feasible for small `n`; it grows fast!).

Comment: Will do! I'm not sure what "bt" is. Is it short for something?

Comment: A binary tree is either (1) empty, or (2) two binary trees, called the "left" and "right" children. A bt string is simply a way to encode a unique binary tree shape as a string.

Comment: Got it, I am familiar with Binary Trees, just didn't think of that is what bt stands for in the above question. Definitely need more practice. Thanks, will definitely try it out!

Comment: @rgamber: A binary tree node is either empty or has two children. An arbitrary tree node has any number of children. We can have a string format for them too. An arbitrary tree string is `X(` followed by zero or more arbitrary tree strings, followed by `)`.  So for example, `X(X()X(X()))` is an arbitrary tree string. How many arbitrary tree strings are there with n X's?  Before you run your program, make a prediction: are there more or fewer arbitrary tree strings with n X's than there are binary tree strings with n x's?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167380/discussion-between-rgamber-and-eric-lippert).